# sending one time password(otp) using outgoing voicecall

Tags: android, ios, mobile, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password

I would like to send the otp code to my users using sms and voice. I already completed sending of otp by sms using clickatell provider.

I would like to do the same by using a outgoing call to the user's phone. 
Just like, whatsapp has the sendsms and call me features.

Can you suggest a good provider and which is cheap as well as implementation in java.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can create this feature using the Twilio API to [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) and then read out the number to user.

You would need to purchase yourself a Twilio number with which to make a call. Then, [use the REST API to create the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) from your number to the user's number. In the API call you would supply a URL so that when the call connects [Twilio would make an HTTP request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) to the URL to find out what to do next. Your URL would need to respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), which is some XML that describes what Twilio should do next. To read out the OTP code you could use the [`<Say>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say).

There isn't a full tutorial on this, but this tutorial shows you [how to make calls from Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/java/servlets).

You could also check out [how to accomplish this with Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/java/servlets), which is a fully featured two factor authentication API that allows you to send SMS messages, make calls and use app based OTPs.

Let me know if this helps at all.