# How to implement OTP through call functionality in Android?

Tags: android, phone-call

I have implemented an OTP feature in my Android application. The user receives the OTP through text message. I want to implement a functionality where the user is able to request the OTP through call in case he/she is not able to receive a text message. How can I do that? 
Thanks!

Comment: We don't design whole features here. This question is too broad.  Also, you have this tagged otp-  that otp is an erlang library, its not the right tag.

Comment: This link can help to solve the problem :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539705/sending-one-time-passwordotp-using-outgoing-voicecall

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check which VOIP provider gives these services and some of them give this kind of services. You just have to go through normal API calls and you will be done.
For the VOIP providers, if your app is for global or is it for local use it depends upon your app. I strongly recommend you go through the 2factors. They provide the voice otp as well as otp through SMS, And their API is also simple to call.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio API's will help to send the SMS and calls to the user.You learn the request and response methods of the API's using the twilio. The Documentation is also available for the same. It also provides the quick start to the voice feature of java language.